# Unterschied zwischen "Angestellte", "Beamte" und "Arbeitnehmer"

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen:

- Beamte
- Angestellte
- Arbeitnehmer

Comment: Diese Frage scheint off-topic zu sein, da sie die deutsche Verwaltung, nicht die deutsche Sprache an sich betrifft.

Comment: What does your research tell you?

Comment: Ich habe das nicht  verstanden .

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... aber für einen Lerner sind es ja zunächst mal Wörter. Warum soll man da nicht kurz drauf eingehen. Dann könnte ich ja, wenn Computerterminologie gefragt wird, auch sagen, das ist nicht pc.stackexchange :)

Comment: @Em1... on Leo.org for example, the translations do overlap

Comment: Could you maybe add some information telling us why after consulting a dictionary such as dict.leo.org you still don't know what the differences are?

Comment: @Emanuel, vielleicht wäre es gar nicht schlecht, wenn Du bei Computerterminologie das Schließen beantragst, sofern es nicht um “finer points of the German language” geht.

Comment: "[Beamte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamter)" is a type of civil servant that is unique to German-speaking countries. It is legally separated from employees, and the term cannot be translated to English.

Comment: "Arbeitnehmer" roughly means "employee" (excluding entrepreneurs, students, judges, soldiers, and Beamte). "Angestellte" are roughly employees that are not blue-collar workers ("Arbeiter").

Comment: @CarstenSchultz. As long as these questions can stand, this one can too.  http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4786/difference-between-jaegermeister-and-waidmann   http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3664/differences-between-klausur-prufung-and-examen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the type of employment. Arbeitnehmer are all employees. Beamte are public servants and Angestellte are no public servants. In some jobs (teachers for example) you can be employed as one or the other.

Comment: Beamte are not employees, they don't do work (instead they provide a service) and they don't receive a salary (instead they receive "aliments").